# PHP DateTime format giving incorrect result

Tags: php, date, validation

I am validating whether a date string is correct and this is the function that I use:

```
public static function date($string, $format = false)
{
    $d = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $string);
    return $d && $d->format($format) === $string;
}
```

When I pass in "11/2019" as the string and "m/Y" as the format. The result of `$d->format($format)` is "12/2019". How can this be?

verified in sandbox: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f792b53cdc58cd82b69c6a4d7e6b7aa72032c929

Any ideas on this one? It doesn't happen to be wrong for any other date combinations than "11/2019".

Comment: Today is October 31 so when you create the date it is creating Nov 31 which becomes December 1. See the more detailed explanation in the duplicate. It will also fail for '2/2019', '4/2019' and '9/2019' today. Tomorrow they will all work fine.

Comment: much appreciated, thanks

Comment: No worries. Lucky you caught it today - it would have worked fine for the next 30 days from tomorrow!

Comment: Yep my thoughts exactly!!